# Hide the Calling Activity from after startActivityForResult returned?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a question about the `startActivityForResult` method:

I have 3 activities: A, B and C. A starts the `startActivityForResult` to launch B, then B will return the result to A. If the resultCode is OK, A will launch C. Like the image shown below:

[image]

According to my test on the devices running Android 2.3.x it always showing activity A for a short period of time before C is launched. But for the devices running 4.x, the activity A will not show up.

So, is there any way to hide A from showing up after B return the result to it?

Comment: Maybe simply start activity instead of `forResult`, and launch C from B if you're happy with the result? Perhaps not a pretty solution but I do see it working.

Comment: @Keyser thx for the quick response. But for some reason, I need the result from B. Otherwise, directly start C from B is the best choice.

Comment: You mean you need it in `A`? There's no way around that? (I understand if there isn't, just wondering)

Comment: Like @Keyser said, you have to start Activity C directly from B. I can't see a use case where you want it return to A and then start C.

Comment: Say if A is menu, B is to start camera, C is to handle the image post processing. B will bring back the result of 1. If the pic is successfully taken; 2. where the img is saved; Upon receiving these result, A will decide to launch C or not. If the result code is ok, then start C, if is cancelled (i.e user pressed back button in B), A will give a toast notification, and the application will remain in A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your camera example, here's how I'd do it:

`A` starts.

`A` opens `B` with `startActivity`.

If a picture is successfully taken (which you check in `B`), send it to `C`, if not,

`finish()` and return to `A`.

So all you need to do is move the verification step to `B`. I see no reason for the menu to verify this.